# fetch Single column from two table

Tags: sql

I am very new in SQL and I am writing this query

```
SELECT
    SalesreturnDetails.[Price]
FROM
    SalesreturnDetails,
    SalesReturn
WHERE
    SalesReturn.Session='12-13';
```

but in SalesReturn Table there are two record and SalesreturnDetails table have 3 record but output is coming 6 rows but I want output should be 3 rows.

Tables are: 
SalesReturn

```
Bill_Number    Session
 2              12-13
 2              12-13
```

SalesReturnDetails

```
Bill_Number    Price
  2             700
  2             900
  2             300
```

Comment: how does your output looked like?

Comment: i mean you desired result.

Comment: What's the PRIMARY KEY on each table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.Price
FROM    SalesReturnDetails a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT Bill_number
            FROM    SalesReturn
            WHERE   Session='12-13'
        ) b ON a.Bill_number = b.Bill_number
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14b3a/2)

Answer (score 1):

You should try an outer join on Bill_Number : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: I think which i am doing it is also like the outerjoin